# Angularjs - using a $scope variabile to change menubar status, link managed by ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying to change menubar's status using a scopa variable that changes according the link but I can't catch what's wrong on this because it's not working.

menubar:

```
    <body ng-app="publicApp">
    ......
               <ul class="nav" ng-controller="LocationController">
                   <li ng-class="{'active': activeURL == 'home', 'gray': activeURL != 'home'}" >
                       <a href="<c:url value="#/"/>"
                          title='<spring:message code="header.home"/>'>
                           <p><spring:message code="header.home"/></p>
                       </a>
                   </li>
                   <li ng-class="{'gray': activeURL == 'contacts', '': activeURL != 'contacts'}">
                    <a title='<spring:message code="header.contacts"/>' href="<c:url value='#/contacts'/>">
                        <p><spring:message code="header.contacts"/></p>
                    </a>
                   </li>
                   <li ng-class="{'gray': activeURL == 'register', '': activeURL != 'register'}">
                    <a title='<spring:message code="header.register"/>' href="<c:url value='#/newUser'/>">
                        <p><spring:message code="header.register"/></p>
                    </a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
    ......

    <div class="jumbotron" style="padding: 50px">
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
.....
</body>
```

Then the app.js

```
var publicApp = angular.module('publicApp', ['ngRoute']);
publicApp.controller("LocationController", function($scope, $location) {
    if($location.$$absUrl.lastIndexOf('/newUser') > 0){
        $scope.activeURL = 'register';
    } else if($location.$$absUrl.lastIndexOf('/contacts') > 0){
        $scope.activeURL = 'home';
    }else{
        $scope.activeURL = 'home';
    }
});
publicApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',
                      { templateUrl: 'login'});
    $routeProvider.when('/newUser',
                      { templateUrl: 'newUser', controller : 'LocationController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

I'm expecting to have menubar's layout changing when user press a link inside it.

Comment: have you tried to debug , to check whether the controller is getting called adn what is the location value?

Comment: Yes, I tried, the controller is called but if I try to display on $scope.activeURL I always get empty value. 
Probably is something about the scope, but I'm a newbie on Angularjs.

Comment: Hold on, Your controller is running... but you are using it in two places, actually.  In one through `ng-controller` and the other through the controller property in the route.  
I don't know if that's what you want, but if you put a `console.log` in it, you should see it twice.  Is that happening?

Comment: You're right, it is loaded once when loading the page, and again when pressing registration button. The behaviour I need is to have $scope.activeURL changing when I press a menu button, so I can use it to put style on the menu.

Comment: thanks guys, I solved issue, it was a matter of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it's a scope matter.
Found solution [here](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication).

I modifyed code in this way:

```
 var publicApp = angular.module('publicApp', ['ngRoute']);


publicApp.controller("LocationController", function($scope, $location) {

    if($location.$$absUrl.lastIndexOf('/newUser') > 0){
        $scope.$parent.activeURL = 'register';
    } else if($location.$$absUrl.lastIndexOf('/contacts') > 0){
        $scope.$parent.activeURL = 'home';
    }else{
        $scope.$parent.activeURL = 'home';
    }
});


publicApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'login', controller : 'LocationController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/newUser', { templateUrl: 'newUser', controller : 'LocationController' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/', controller : 'LocationController'  });
});
```

Not elegant but working.
Controller was nested, then I needed to call $scope.$parent to set globally activeURL variable.